# How to locally generate a preview of the web page for my cabal package?

Tags: haskell, cabal

From the [Hackage check/upload](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/upload.html) page:

> #### Checking a Cabal package
>
> Re-uploading a package with the same version number is not permitted, so you might want to do some checking before uploading:
>
> - You could check that your source bundle builds, including the haddock documentation if it's a library.
> - The following form checks that a package is uploadable, warns about sundry other matters, and **presents a preview of the web page for the package**. It does not add the package to the database.

(my emphasis)

How do I generate a preview of the web page for the package locally? i.e. without using that website form?

(The "web page for the package" is e.g. [this is QuickCheck's](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).)

Comment: I think that page is generated by [one of these scripts](http://code.haskell.org/~ross/hackage-scripts/).

Comment: It turns out I don't have enough time to investigate this properly :-( But thank you anyway for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `cabal haddock` to generate this page. This will generate the documentation in `dist/doc/html/<library-or-executable-name>/index.html`.

Additionally, you can edit your `~/.cabal/config` file to include the line:

```
documentation: True
```

This will automatically install documentation for all of the packages you install with Cabal, and you will get a list of all installed modules on the system in the `~/.cabal/share/doc/index.html` file; this is useful for `ghci` sessions or when you want to find out which package contains which modules, etc.

Comment: `dist/doc/html/<foo>/index.html` doesn't include the Properties section that appears on the page on Hackage.

Comment: Most of that information isn't available locally. For example, you can't locally know which packages are available on Hackage that match your dependency ranges (If you specify `mtl==2.*` as a dependency, you can't know that 2.0.0, 2.0.0.1, etc are the candidates that match that dependency on Hackage); you need access to the Hackage databases to figure that out, so Dependencies can't be calculated.

The same can be said for every other field except License, Copyright, Author, Maintainer, and Stability (and some others), but these are just copied verbatim from your `.cabal` file anyways.

Comment: Most of that information is in the .cabal file, and the value here is that it's easier (for some people, me included) to spot typos and other minor errors when that information is presented in its published form, rather than in the original plain text. Still, I am accepting this answer because it seems to be as close as I can get to what I want without shaving yaks.